# Button that calls print source specifies primefaces

Tags: primefaces, printers

I am printing a panel with this information primefaces button. 
But I need to send this impression with a smaller font, how do I do that in this code?

```
                <p:commandButton value="Imprimir" styleClass="btn btn-primary"  >
                     <p:printer target="information" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

This is my component information I want to print:
In printing occupies an entire sheet and I want to reduce the font when printing call

```
    <p:panel id="information">

        <h3 class="text-warning">#{msg['text-warning']}</h3>
        <p>#{msg['text-valueReference']}</p>
        <p class="lead text-primary">#{msg['text-time']}*</p>
        <p>
            <strong>#{msg['lbl-band1']}:</strong>#{' '}#{msg['text-band1']}
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>#{msg['lbl-band2']}:</strong>#{' '}#{msg['text-band2']}
        </p>
        <p>
            <small> #{msg['text-leiBand']} </small>
        </p>
        <p class="lead text-primary">#{msg['text-Baggage']}</p>
        <p>
            <strong>De mão:</strong>#{' '}#{msg['text-HandLuggage']}
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Normal:</strong>#{' '}#{msg['text-NormalBaggage']}
        </p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>#{msg['text-noCharge']}</p>
            <small> #{msg['text-noChargeVolumes']} </small>
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote>
            <p>#{msg['text-Charge']}:</p>
            <small> #{msg['text-ChargeVolumes']} </small>
        </blockquote>
        <p>
            <small> #{msg['text-leiVolumes']} </small>
        </p>
        <p class="lead text-primary">#{msg['text-optionalTransport']}</p>


        <p>
            <strong></strong>#{msg['text-optionalTransportValue']}
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong> </strong>
        </p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>#{msg['text-animals']}:</p>
            <small> #{msg['text-animalsValues']} </small>
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote>
            <p>#{msg['text-large-bags']}:</p>
            <small> #{msg['text-largeBagsValue']} </small>
        </blockquote>

        <p>
            <small> #{msg['text-obs']} </small>
        </p>
    </p:panel>
```

Comment: Does your component with id="information" have only text?

Comment: I edited the question and includes the component has some tags and text.

Comment: You cannot do this out of the box. `p:print` will always print the component as it is. What you can do is, on your `p:commandButton` put an onclick handler that reduces the font-size in your panel.